# jQuery autocomplete with java not filtering result

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery auto complete. It's not filtering my result. Currently when you type in a letter in the text field it shows all the result in autocomplete without filtering by the letters that you type in. I seen the jQuery documentation online it said that source: string needs to be filtered on the server side but i don't know how to do that. I would also like the filtering result to show the address, zip code of the result but when you click the autocomplete option it should only enter the first and last name. How do i accomplish this.

Here is my controller code:

```
public class Con{
    public Response execute(PageExext k) throws Exception {

        TextResponse tr = k.createTextResponse();

        r.setContentType("application/json");

        try {

            String term = etk.getParers().getSle("term");
            String sqlJson = t.creaQL("Select c_first_name, c_last_name from t_cct").fetchJSON();
            r.put("aadata", sqlJson);

        }catch (Exception e ) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return r;

    }

}
```

Here is my javascript autocomplete function:

```
function caseInete() {

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery("#C, #Caey, #CaseIr, #Casorney").autocomplete({

                //  autoFocus: true,

                // source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]

                source : function (request, response) {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url : "page.request.do?page=test",
                        type : "GET",
                        data : {
                            term : request.term
                        },
                        dataType : "json",
                        success : function(data) {  

                            var dataArray = [];
                            for(var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
                                // Add items to array
                                dataArray.push(data[k].c_first_name + " " + data[k].c_last_name);
                            }

                            response(dataArray);

                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL query to considere your term and add an order by:

```
String sqlJson = etk.createSQL("Select c_first_name, c_last_name from t_contact where c_first_name like '%" + term + "%' order by c_first_name").fetchJSON();
```

You also should use a prepared statement unlike in my example.

Comment: that works for filtering but i would like to show the address and zip code for the result but when i click on the result it should only enter the first and last name how do i do that? The reason why i am doing this is because sometime people might have two of the same record but different address and the only way to know who has the right or wrong address is to be able show the address information as with the name but only enter the name when the result is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot write a comment because of my reputation :( 
If you need more data then the firstname and lastname, then you have to edit your query and add also the other columns within the select clause. But like cheb1k4 said you have to use a prepared statement at minimum because of SQL Injections otherwise. And you also tagged with JEE, so have a look for a persistence framework with the use of JPA. But that depends of course on your size of your project.